# Naming Entities and Protocols

Tags: swift, frameworks, carthage, swift-package-manager

#### Background

When developing an application, my approach (rightly or wrongly) is to separate the logic into a Framework (Kit)
The reason(s) for this are fairly straight forward ..
• I like being able to test the logic in isolation
• I like that it forces me to forget about the UI and any UI assumptions
• I like that I am free to create the app using a separate UI .. depending on device (iPhone, Watch .. Apple TV .. Command Line Utility)

#### The Problem

because I like the logic in a separate framework .. I have introduced a complexity in terms of access modifiers (Public, Internal, Private) for classes, structs, enums, methods, properties.

What I have most trouble with is **properties** (and properties of Entities in particular)
I prefer not to expose the setter to the consumer of the Framework (i.e. the UI Application)
Within a Module I would typically use the.
`private(set) var nameOfProperty`
approach.
However this isn’t an option to me in entities of a framework.

So for a framework, I would much rather return a **Protocol** describing the interface of an **Entity**
.. i.e. it’s writable properties, it’s read-only properties and it’s accessible methods

We (Swift Developers) have been encouraged down the route of naming Protocols according to a behaviour .. however,
.. for example, a **Football/Soccer Team Selection** framework I wouldn’t want to be passing back and forth something that conforms to ‘Player-able’, ‘Manager-able’, ‘Fixture-able’
.. I want to pass back and forth a ‘Player’, ‘Manager’, ‘Fixture’ (as the consumer would rightfully expect)

#### Question

What should I be naming my **Entity** (assuming it conforms to a commonly known as Protocol) ?
*Understandably, we can not have a Protocol called* `protocol Player` *and* `class Player`

*Some Suggested Ideas*

**Idea 1**: Use underscoring within the framework (my most likely approach)
e.g.

```
public protocol Player {
    public var name: String { get }
}

public class _Player: Player {
..
}
```

**Idea 2**: Don’t use protocols, but use computed properties instead (not preferred)
e.g.

```
public class Player {
    private var _name: String

    public var name: String {
        get {
            return _name
        }
}
```

**Idea 3**: Don’t use protocols, because you're the only consumer then trust yourself and make everything public 
e.g.

```
public class Player {
    public var name: String
}
```

**Idea 4**: Use a substitute name within the framework (a bit like underscoring)
e.g.

```
public protocol Player {
    public var name: String { get }
}

public class PlayerEntity: Player {
..
}
or 
public class PlayerImpl: Player {
..
}
or 
public class PlayerObj: Player {
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd go with `Player: PlayerProtocol`, unless you are going to be using the protocol much more often. There are some examples of this in the standard library, such as [`StringProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol) and [`IteratorProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol).

Comment: Thank you @john .. what does the consumer of the framework see at the call site ?  As a consumer, I would probably expect to be interacting with a `Player` (not a `PlayerProtocol`)

Comment: Would both `Player` and `PlayerProtocol` defined in the framework, or just the protocol? I may be misunderstanding, but it seems like you'd always be dealing with a concrete type that implements the protocol, right?

Comment: It also just occurred to me that `public private(set) var name: String` is probably an easier way of getting a stored read-only property, without needing protocols. Is there a reason that doesn't work for you?